# LinkedIn sharing SHARE_URL#HASH URL Param

Tags: linkedin-api

I am faced with a LinkedIn sharing issue.
This issue probably reproducible from March 1st 2019.

I share some url e.g. https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=SHARE_URL#HASH
Worked before: link in post(href) - SHARE_URL#HASH
Works now: link in post(href) - value of og:url meta tag from SHARE_URL#HASH page

So we lose request parameters in SHARE_URL and #HASH

How we can pass link for LinkedIn post into request?

Comment: Do u want to share on linked in or Via linked in ?

Comment: I want share article via button.

Comment: I want share some query parameters too. This query parameters is analytics for my site. For example SHARE_URL?user_from=twitter, SHARE_URL?user_from=facebook, SHARE_URL?user_from=lenkedin. Facebook and twitter works correctly. But linkedin sharing does not use link directly for href post, it uses og:url could be.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do [URL-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) with parameters you are feeding to another URL.  So, this is what you should want...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=SHARE_URL%23HASH
```

Remember, URL's use things like `?` and `#` to indicate a special argument occurring after this character.  So, for instance, `example.com/share.php?title=thisistitleright?&...`, how would the browser know that the first `?` indicates the `GET` param and the second `?` is a part of the title argument?  Easy: URL encoding.

In case you want to know more: **[Official LinkedIn Share Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**